# How to check if a var is null in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working with SQL Server 2012 express and I want to check if the result of a Select is null.

This is my sql statement:

```
Set @xml = (Select DATOS from LOTES_ANTERIORES WHERE NOMBRE_LOTE = @nombreLote AND PRODUCTO = @producto)

SET @xmlString = cast(@xml as nvarchar(max))
```

How can I check if `@xml` is null?

I'm not sure if `@xmlString` will return null or not if `@xml` is null.

Comment: In addition to my answer below, yes, `@xmlString` will be null if `@xml` is null too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF @xml IS NULL PRINT 'It's null!'
```

Or to perform more actions, like this:

```
IF @xml IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT 'XML is NULL'
    PRINT 'XML is NULL'
END
```